# Getting 2 title bar in xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

There are two title bars in my app when I navigate to another page:

The first one contains back button and the second one contains title of content page. My question is how is it possible to merge them into a single title bar. Here's my code:

Page1.cs

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Page2()));
```

Page2.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp1.Page2" Title="Page 2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpsfC.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first page in your app add a new `NavigationPage` and your page within it:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPage());
```

For the second page, do not create a new `NavigationPage`, just Push a new page onto the existing `NavigationPage`:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
```